# How to loop a function over all elements of a vector except one and store the result in separate columns of a data frame

Tags: r, function, loops, multiple-columns

I have a data frame with several columns. I want to run a function [pmax() in this case] over all columns whose name is stored in a vector except one, and store the result in new separate columns. At the end, I would also like to store the names of all new columns in a separate vector. A minimal example would be:

```
Name <- c("Case 1", "Case 2", "Case 3", "Case 4", "Case 5")
C1 <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
C2 <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
C3 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
C4 <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
Data <- data.frame(Name, C1, C2, C3, C4)

var.min <- function(data, col.names){
                    new.df <- data

                    # This is how I would do it outside a function and without loop:
                    new.df$max.def.col.exc.1 <- pmax(new.df$C2, new.df$C3)
                    new.df$max.def.col.exc.2 <- pmax(new.df$C1, new.df$C3)
                    new.df$max.def.col.exc.3 <- pmax(new.df$C1, new.df$C2)
                    
                    new.columns <- c("max.def.col.exc.1", "max.def.col.exc.2", "max.def.col.exc.3")

                    return(new.df)
}

new.df <- var.min(Data,
                  col.names= c("C1", "C2", "C3"))
```

The result should look like:

```
    Name C1 C2 C3 C4 max.def.col.exc.1 max.def.col.exc.2 max.def.col.exc.3
1 Case 1  1  0  0  1                 0                 1                 1
2 Case 2  0  1  1  1                 1                 1                 1
3 Case 3  1  1  0  0                 1                 1                 1
4 Case 4  1  1  0  1                 1                 1                 1
5 Case 5  0  0  0  0                 0                 0                 0
```

Anyone with an idea? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you taking `pmax` of two columns at a time?.  Your description says different though

Comment: "I want to run a function [pmax() in this case] over all columns whose name is stored in a vector except one". In my vector, there are three column names stored. I.e. the function should run over two columns. If there were four columns stored in the vector, the function should run each time over the remaining three, etc. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: In the data showed there are 4 columns C1, to C4.  So should that be 3 instead of 2?

Comment: I put a fourth column to show that it should be disregarded, since I only selected col.names= c("C1", "C2", "C3").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R solution with `combn`. It gets all pairwise combinations of the column names and calls a function computing `pmax`.

Note that the order of the expected output columns is the same as the one output by the code below. If the columns vector is `c("C1", "C2", "C3")`, the order will be different.

Note also that the function is now a one-liner and accepts combinations of any number of columns, 2, 3 or more.

```
var.min <- function(cols, data) Reduce(pmax, data[cols])

cols <- c("C3", "C2", "C1")
combn(cols, 2, var.min, data = Data)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    1    1
#[2,]    1    1    1
#[3,]    1    1    1
#[4,]    1    1    1
#[5,]    0    0    0
```

Now it's just a matter of assigning column names and `cbind`ing with the input data.

```
tmp <- combn(cols, 2, var.min, data = Data)
colnames(tmp) <- paste0("max.def.col.exc.", seq_along(cols))
Data <- cbind(Data, tmp)
rm(tmp)    # final clean-up
```

Comment: I have thought through the code and complexified it to my needs. Then, I came along the issue with the order of the columns that you mention. May I ask why the code reverses the order?

Comment: @CNiessen It's `combn` that puts the combinations of the 1st element with the others first, then the 2nd, etc. In your expected output the order is the same as in mine. If you don't care much about the difference, I would use the order in the original df.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation, makes sense! I solved it by reversing the order of the elements before applying `combn`.

Comment: I also realised that `cmbn` was dependent on the number of the selected conditions with `n = length(cols) - 1`. I thus added a line at the beginning: `col.nb = length(cols) - 1` and adapted `tmp <- combn(cols, col.nb, var.min, data = Data)`.

Comment: @CNiessen If that's the use case, then yes, it makes sense to have `n` depend on the 1st argument.